# first item is getting selected in simple type access list box

Tags: ms-access

Find  my  vba

Private Sub Search_Click()

Dim VarItem As Variant

Dim Strsearch As String
Dim Sql As String
Dim ctrl As Control

Set ctrl = Me.LbobDriveType

If ctrl.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then

For Each VerItem In ctrl.ItemsSelected

Strsearch = Strsearch & ctrl.Column(VarItem)

Next VerItem

MsgBox (Strsearch)

Sql = "SELECT Database.[Record _ID], Database.PhysicalVIN, Database.LogicalVIN, Database.VERSION, Database.BODY_STYLE, Database.ENGINE_TYPES, Database.BODY_EXTERIOR_COLOR, Database.INDIA_OR_EXPORT, Database.DRIVE_TYPES, Database.TRANSMISSION_TYPES, Database.FUEL_TYPE, Database.MARKET, Database.MARKET_CATEGORY " _
    & "FROM [Database] where DRIVE_TYPES in('" & Strsearch & "')"

```
MsgBox (Sql)

   End If
```

Me.SbfRecord.Form.RecordSource = Sql
Me.SbfRecord.Form.Requery

end sub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ8V8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y5L2.png)

Comment: Fix formatting.

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question? BTW: You're missing an `End If` somewhere...

Comment: I am having listbox in access Form where  I have put two value " LHD"."RHD". I have chosen list type - simple for multi select.  Duplicate value is getting selected  after selecting both the Values. like RHDRHD or LHDLHD.  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you want the two marked entries of the listbox to be displayed in the message box instead of twice the first one?

If so, the code should work well except of the fact that there is a typo (`VarItem` vs `VerItem`) and an `End If` missing.

So I think your problem could be that there is more than one column defined in the listbox?
Maybe the first column is hidden and contains `RHD` for all rows?

Comment: Thanks  My  Friend!  Issue was of  Typo..  Feeling relieved.